# How to check a value from a nother table

Tags: sql-server

I have Table:

```
create table Authorized(
diver_number int not null,
level_name char(30) not null,
constraint PK_Authorized primary key (diver_number, level_name),
Constraint FK_diver_number1 foreign key (diver_number) references Diver(diver_number)
on update cascade on delete cascade,
Constraint FK_level_name foreign key (level_name) references Level(name)on update
cascade on delete cascade,
club_number int Constraint FK_club_number foreign key (club_number) references DivingClub(number)
on update cascade on delete cascade not null,
authorization_date date not null,
picture image)
```

And atable:

```
create table Works_for(
diver_number int not null,
club_number int not null,
constraint PK_Works_for primary key (diver_number, club_number),
Constraint FK_diver_number2 foreign key (diver_number) references Diver(diver_number)
on update cascade on delete cascade ,
Constraint FK_club_number2 foreign key (club_number) references DivingClub (number)on     update
cascade on delete cascade,
start_working_date date not null,
end_working_date date)
```

When i add diver_number to table Works_for, i want to check if this diver is a "Guide" (level_name in Authorized table). How can i check it?

Comment: Are you trying to check this with a constraint or in code? It isn't clear what you mean.

Comment: I want to add a constraint to check it

Comment: I want to allow adding a new "Works_for" only if the diver is a Guide

Comment: You can do this a UDF. Basically create a scalar function that will return 1 or 0. Then your constraint would use this scalar function. Something along these lines. CHECK(dbo.IsGuide(diver_number) = 1)

Comment: @sean
I tried that, but it seems like i can't find the way to write the function.
no matter what i write in the function, it let me add the diver

Comment: How do you know if a diver is a "Guide"?

Comment: @sean

`    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checkADate(@id int)
    RETURNS date
    as
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @date date=null
    DECLARE @level char(5)='Guide'
    select @date = (select authorization_date from Authorized WHERE         diver_number = @id and @level =level_name)
    return @date
END
GO`

Comment: Why are you returning a date? I thought you want to know if the user was in the table?

Comment: @ sean
I do.
But i don't know what i need to return for checking if the user is in the table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think your scalar function would be more like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checkADate(@diver_number int) RETURNS BIT AS 
BEGIN
    declare @Found bit 

    select @Found = count(*)
    from Authorized 
    WHERE diver_number = @diver_number 
        and level_name = 'Guide'

    return @Found 

END
```

Comment: Probably not a good name for this. Should use a name that is more descriptive of what it does.

Comment: And with this function, what do i need to write in the check?
CHECK(dbo.IsGuide(diver_number)..?

Comment: CHECK(dbo.checkADate(diver_number) = 1)

Comment: In case you are wondering, any value >= 1 when cast as a bit will be 1.

Comment: You are Wonderful! 
would the function i wrote before will return the date, if it's not null? can i use it if i need to know the date?

Comment: Sure you could do that. Just change the check for IS NOT NULL

Comment: i use this function to return a date:
`CREATE FUNCTION getEndWotkingDate (@id int) 
 RETURNS date 
BEGIN
    declare @endDate date 

    select @endDate = end_working_date
    from tblWorks_for 
    WHERE diver_number = @id


    return @endDate 

END
go`

the date field i returning can be null or can contain a date. 
i want to add check. if the field is null or after other date.
i used: 
`CONSTRAINT CK_Date check(dbo.getEndWotkingDate(guide) is null or dbo.getEndWotkingDate(guide) <= date_of_diving ))`
But it doesn't working.

Comment: What does not working mean? Do you get an error message? Does it allow incorrect values to be inserted?

Comment: Allow incorrect values to be inserted. 
The date the method returning is 2005/03/03. the date_of_diving is 2008/05/05. It shouldn't let me insert it

Comment: What datatype is date_of_diving?

Comment: Short of more details there isn't much I can do here. I created a dummy table with this function and it does exactly what it should. There is something not right in your code. Unfortunately I don't know what that might be. One thing I changed was to modify the constraint so it doesn't need to run the scalar twice. CONSTRAINT CK_Date check(date_of_diving <= isnull(dbo.getEndWotkingDate(guide), date_of_diving))

Comment: Your CONSTRAINT change solved the problem!!
There is other problem now. After i insert values seccesfuly, When i choose "Edit top 200 rows" i get an error:  invalid object name 'tblDiving_club'.
What could be the problem?

Comment: No clue. but I would avoid using SSMS to edit data. It is buggy. Use a query instead.